# Explaining makefile % as well as $< and $@

Tags: syntax, makefile

```
xpi_built := $(build_dir)/$(install_rdf) \
             $(build_dir)/$(chrome_manifest) \
             $(chrome_jar_file) \
             $(default_prefs)

xpi_built_no_dir := $(subst $(build_dir)/,,$(xpi_built))

$(xpi_file): $(build_dir) $(xpi_built)
 @echo "Creating XPI file."
 cd $(build_dir); $(ZIP) ../$(xpi_file) $(xpi_built_no_dir)
 @echo "Creating XPI file. Done!"

$(build_dir)/%: %
 cp -f $< $@

$(build_dir):
 @if [ ! -x $(build_dir) ]; \
  then \
    mkdir $(build_dir); \
  fi
```

can anyone explain me this makefile part? particularly interested in

- `$(build_dir)/%: %` as well as `$<` and `$@` directives
- two labels `$(build_dir)` exists, I guess both are executed, but in which order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(build_dir)/%: %
    cp -f $< $@
```

This is a static pattern rule which uses automatic variables in its command; `$<` expands to the leftmost prerequisite, `$@` expands to the target. If you try to make `$(build_dir)/foo` (whatever `$(build_dir)` is), Make will treat this rule as

```
$(build_dir)/foo: foo
    cp -f foo $(build_dir)/foo
```

The next rule,

```
$(build_dir):
    @if [ ! -x $(build_dir) ]; \
  then \
  mkdir $(build_dir); \
  fi
```

is for `$(build_dir)` itself, and is unnecessarily complicated. It says "if `$(build_dir)` doesn't exist, then mkdir it", and it could be written this way:

```
$(build_dir):
    mkdir $@
```

It looks as if your primary target is `$(xpi_file)`:

```
$(xpi_file): $(build_dir) $(xpi_built)
```

So Make will first make `$(build_dir)` (if necessary), then the members of the list `%(xpi_built)`, which includes a couple of things of the form `$(build_dir)/%`. Once those are done, it will execute the commands of this rule: it will cd into `$(build_dir)`, zip some things up, and `echo` a couple of messages.

Comment: @Beta
Thanks for detailed explanation. Do you know any good e-book for make?

Comment: @Michael e-book? Lukáš Lalinský has cited the GNUMake manual, which is the best documentation I know of. There are also "Advanced Auto-Dependency Generation", which is, well, advanced, and "Recursive Make Considered Harmful", a popular reference which I disagree with.

Answer (score 0):

See [Pattern Rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules) and [Automatic Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) in the GNU make documentation. The first rule matches files inside `$(build_dir)`, not `$(build_dir)` itself. `$<` expands to the list of prerequisites of the current rule, `$@` is the target for the current rule.

Comment: not quite right -- `$<` expands to (just) the first prerequisite.  `$^` expands to all the prerequisites